# What provides libicui18n.so.52.1()(64bit) on Fedora (23)?

Tags: qt5, fedora

I'm trying to install libQt5Core from an rpm and I get:

> Error: nothing provides libicui18n.so.52.1()(64bit) needed by libQt5Core5-5.5.1-4.1.x86_64

Comment: Nothing provides libicui18n.so.52.1. So, find an *.rpm package that provides the ICU library of the version 52 and install it. ICU is a library for the character encoding handling.

Answer (score 3):

There is newer version:

```
dnf whatprovides libicui18n*
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:00:14 ago on Fri Jan 29 13:58:14 2016.
libicu-54.1-5.fc23.x86_64 : International Components for Unicode - libraries
Repo        : @System
```

Where do you install the libQt5Core from? The official repositories should not require packages versions that are not available.

Comment: I have libicu installed

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that RPM to install the QT 5 core libraries. I'm guessing that you have a package for openSUSE (because that's what comes up when I Google for "libQt5Core rpm"). In Fedora, the package you want is **`qt5-qtbase`**. Install that with:

```
sudo dnf install qt5-qtbase
```

It happens that our version in Fedora 23 is *also* version 5.5.1, so I *think* that'll be what you really need here.

If you're doing software development, you might want to pull in the KDE Frameworks 5 development group, which is mostly QT stuff and which will get you set up for building programs against that, which might be what you're trying to do:

```
sudo dnf groupinstall kf5-software-development
```